# How can I convert my sql query into a View?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know we cannot use declare in a view, however I have no choice now...

is there a way I can use the below in a view, and how can this be done?

```
    Declare @q varchar(MAX)

;WITH N AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT FD_2A7417DC Pvt_Col 
  FROM   FD_Documents
), C (Cols) As (
  SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Pvt_Col) 
                FROM   N
                ORDER BY Pvt_Col
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
              , 1, 1, '')
)
SELECT @q 
       = 'SELECT ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Name
               , Surname, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
               , End_Date, Type
               , ' + Cols + ' 
          FROM  (SELECT FD_0D39C6B0 AS Company, FD_DDD24E25 AS Date_Of_Birth, FD_74290EA9 AS Department, FD_2A7417DC AS Document_Type, FD_E3421C61 AS Name
                      , FD_2B9CFA8C AS Surname, FD_96990BE2 AS ID_Number, FD_E6621D8A as Passport_No, FD_3744C28A AS Job_Title, FD_903EBB60 as Start_Date
                      , FD_9BBAD0CA AS End_Date, FD_AE108F93 as Type
                 FROM FD_Documents
                ) x
                PIVOT 
                (COUNT(Document_Type) FOR Document_Type in (' + Cols + ')) pvt'
FROM C

execute(@q)
```

**Update 15/08/2014**

This is were I'm at now.

```
create function dbo.tvf_getDocumentType()
returns @t table(ColName int FD_0D39C6B0 AS Company, FD_DDD24E25 AS Date_Of_Birth, FD_74290EA9 AS Department, FD_2A7417DC AS Document_Type, FD_E3421C61 AS Name
                      , FD_2B9CFA8C AS Surname, FD_96990BE2 AS ID_Number, FD_E6621D8A as Passport_No, FD_3744C28A AS Job_Title, FD_903EBB60 as Start_Date
                      , FD_9BBAD0CA AS End_Date, FD_AE108F93 as Type)
as
begin
   Declare @q varchar(MAX)

;WITH N AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT FD_2A7417DC Pvt_Col 
  FROM   FD_Documents
), C (Cols) As (
  SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Pvt_Col) 
                FROM   N
                ORDER BY Pvt_Col
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
              , 1, 1, '')
)
SELECT @q 
       = 'SELECT ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Name
               , Surname, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
               , End_Date, Type
               , ' + Cols + ' 
          FROM  (SELECT FD_0D39C6B0 AS Company, FD_DDD24E25 AS Date_Of_Birth, FD_74290EA9 AS Department, FD_2A7417DC AS Document_Type, FD_E3421C61 AS Name
                      , FD_2B9CFA8C AS Surname, FD_96990BE2 AS ID_Number, FD_E6621D8A as Passport_No, FD_3744C28A AS Job_Title, FD_903EBB60 as Start_Date
                      , FD_9BBAD0CA AS End_Date, FD_AE108F93 as Type
                 FROM FD_Documents
                ) x
                PIVOT 
                (COUNT(Document_Type) FOR Document_Type in (' + Cols + ')) pvt'
FROM C

execute(@q)

end
```

Error Message. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tvf_getDocumentType, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'FD_0D39C6B0'.

Im now going into uncharted water with this code for me.

Comment: You can't since views are static (you can't paramterize them). Use a procedure instead.

Comment: You have to use a stored procedure.   Not possible in a view.

Comment: I Don't normally use procedures? how would i go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start looking at this link right [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx) for starters.   However, your stored procedure should look something like this:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[getDocumentType]    Script Date: 8/4/2014 1:11:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getDocumentType]

AS
BEGIN
    Declare @q varchar(MAX)

    ;WITH N AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT FD_2A7417DC Pvt_Col 
      FROM   FD_Documents
    ), C (Cols) As (
      SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Pvt_Col) 
                    FROM   N
                    ORDER BY Pvt_Col
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                  , 1, 1, '')
    )
    SELECT @q 
           = 'SELECT ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Name
                   , Surname, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
                   , End_Date, Type
                   , ' + Cols + ' 
              FROM  (SELECT FD_0D39C6B0 AS Company, FD_DDD24E25 AS Date_Of_Birth, FD_74290EA9 AS Department, FD_2A7417DC AS Document_Type, FD_E3421C61 AS Name
                          , FD_2B9CFA8C AS Surname, FD_96990BE2 AS ID_Number, FD_E6621D8A as Passport_No, FD_3744C28A AS Job_Title, FD_903EBB60 as Start_Date
                          , FD_9BBAD0CA AS End_Date, FD_AE108F93 as Type
                     FROM FD_Documents
                    ) x
                    PIVOT 
                    (COUNT(Document_Type) FOR Document_Type in (' + Cols + ')) pvt'
    FROM C

    execute(@q)
END
GO
```

You should then be able run an exec getDocumentType to retrieve the data (or through your front end code, however you were going to retrieve it).

**UPDATE ON 08/12/2014**

Based on our conversation in the comments, you could also go down the route of a table valued function, which shouldn't look too different than a stored procedure.  I would suggest the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvf_getDocumentType()
RETURNS TABLE
    AS
RETURN
    (
        /*
        Put all code between the BEGIN and END here
        */
    )
GO
```

You should be able do then do the following:

```
select * dbo.tvf_getDocumentType()
```

This select statement should be able to go into a view.

**UPDATE ON 8/14/2014**

There's apparently 2 ways to use table valued functions, and the option mentioned above is one way.  The second option is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661505/declare-variable-in-table-valued-function).  I'm not sure how to exactly tweak your query to go along with it, but you would have to setup in this fashion:

```
create function dbo.tvf_getDocumentType()
returns @T table(ColName int /*list necessary columns here*/)
as
begin
  /*insert code here*/
end
```

You may have to modify your dynamic query to select your items *into the table variable* as part of your execution.  I think I may need to do more research on this option.

**Update on 8/19/2014**

Based on your notes below, what happens when you do this?  Referenced Setup listed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server).

```
create function dbo.tvf_getDocumentType()
returns @TableResults TABLE (
    /*Please adjust your data types according to your column structures.
      Data types listed here are strictly for explanation and is just a 
      guess on what you have.*/
    ID_Number int NOT NULL,
    Company varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    Date_Of_Birth datetime NOT NULL, 
    Department varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    Name varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    Surname varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    Passport_No varchar(16) NOT NULL, 
    Job_Title varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
    Start_Date datetime NOT NULL,
    End_Date datetime NOT NULL, 
    Type varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    Cols varchar(32) NOT NULL
    )
as
begin
    Declare @q varchar(MAX)

    ;WITH N AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT FD_2A7417DC Pvt_Col 
      FROM   FD_Documents
    ), C (Cols) As (
      SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Pvt_Col) 
                    FROM   N
                    ORDER BY Pvt_Col
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                  , 1, 1, '')
    )
    SELECT @q 
           = 'INSERT INTO  @TableResults
            (ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Name
                   , Surname, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
                   , End_Date, Type, Cols) 
            SELECT ID_Number, Company, Date_Of_Birth, Department, Name
                   , Surname, Passport_No, Job_Title, Start_Date
                   , End_Date, Type
                   , ' + Cols + ' 
              FROM  (SELECT FD_0D39C6B0 AS Company, FD_DDD24E25 AS Date_Of_Birth, FD_74290EA9 AS Department, FD_2A7417DC AS Document_Type, FD_E3421C61 AS Name
                          , FD_2B9CFA8C AS Surname, FD_96990BE2 AS ID_Number, FD_E6621D8A as Passport_No, FD_3744C28A AS Job_Title, FD_903EBB60 as Start_Date
                          , FD_9BBAD0CA AS End_Date, FD_AE108F93 as Type
                     FROM FD_Documents
                    ) x
                    PIVOT 
                    (COUNT(Document_Type) FOR Document_Type in (' + Cols + ')) pvt'
    FROM C

    execute(@q)

return
end
```

This should work, though I can't test your query.  Once done, run the following line:

```
select * from dbo.tvf_getDocumentType()
```

If it works then, you should be able to throw that into a view.   I'm at a loss beyond this, if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Tiny Haitian, this is perfect. thank you so much. No when I run the exec getDocumentType, it gives me an error.

Comment: Just find out that the front end software can only cater for Select statements or views, can I save the SP in a view or create a Select statement on my SP

Comment: I've never tried to do a stored procedure inside a view (not sure if possible), but I can research too.   will keep you posted.

Comment: No problem.   After a little bit of research, you may have to go the route of a table valued function, which would give you a similar setup.   Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916784/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-a-view).   I've messed around a little with table valued functions and will post another code set shortly.

Comment: Hey @user3906930, Check my update and let me know if it works.   I can't fully test your query, but I was able to test the suggested setup with dummy info and create/test both the function and view with no issue.

Comment: Hi @Tiny Haitian, thank you for the response, I insert my original code, but it gave me an error. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tvf_getDocumentType, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare'

Comment: I added an update again; I'd have to do more research, but I think this should point you to the right direction.

Comment: HI @Serpiton, I know you have help before, Please could you also have a look at this?

Comment: Is there anyone that can help?

Comment: I think I may have exhausted my last bit of suggestion, but give yet another look to my update.   Please let me know if it works.   I'm at a loss beyond this, if it doesn't work. I also noticed after my code update, that you have to specify the data type for the columns as opposed to listing your columns names as something else.

Comment: Hi @Tiny Haitian, I get this error Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure tvf_getDocumentType, Line 52
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.